# Visual Studio 2019 error: An error occured launching IISexpress.Unable to launch the configured visual studio development web server. Access denied

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, iis-express

I was developing my project in vs2019. It was working before but last two days it is showing this error:

[image]

An error occured launching IISexpress.Unable to launch the configured visual studio development web server. Access is denied.VS2019

Have anyone faced this issue?

Tried removing .vs folder

Comment: did you run VS as admin?

Comment: Is this happening for just one project or does it also happen if you create a new ASP.NET Core project?

Comment: @PowerMouse I don't have priviledge to run as admin. but previously it was working for me

Comment: @Xerillio Yes other projects are running fine. Only for this project it is showing error.

Comment: would you mind to attach launchSettings.json and appsettings.Development.json
(please hide sencetive data as a connection string)